# Derivation of Transfer Functions for Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filters, bayesian-estimation

Hi All: I'm  somewhat familiar with the kalman filter from a statistical point of view. But lately I've been trying to familarize myself with the linear systems-EE way of looking at it. So, I've been trying to read the Hannan and Deistler 1988 text slowly. I find it difficult and there is
material in there that I don't follow so this  is what my question is about.

I will write down verbatim what the book has and then explain the parts of it that I don't understand. I don't expect the actual detailed answer but rather a book or notes that explain the derivation. I'm totally new to this notation and terminology so maybe my questions can be easily answered but I don't expect it ? In fact, notes or a reference would still be appreciated even if the answers are straightforward.

Quote from Hannan and Deistler: Page 8

> As will be shown, equations ... can be transformed into a state space system
>
> 1.1.22)$ ~~  x(t+1) = Fx(t) + Lz(t) + K \epsilon(t) $
>
> 1.1.23)  $ ~~ y(t) = H x(t) + \epsilon(t) $
>
> where $F \in R^{n \times n}$,  $L \in R^{n \times m}$,
>   $K \in R^{n \times s}$ and $H \in R^{s \times n}$.

Then there about five pages before the authors comes back to these equations above. I won't quote these five pages but they are mostly about how to use the lag operator to and the z-generating function. Although I find these pages confusing, I do understand the concept of a lag operator. I have a feeling that, if someone can answer my question or point to a useful reference or notes, then they won't need these pages. If someone does need them, I can copy them and send them in a pdf.

So, now I continue to where the authors comes back to above and I quote:

Hannan and Deistler, page 14

> For a state space system (1.1.22), (1.1.23) we have det$(I - Fz) = 1$ for
>   $z = 0$ and thus there always exists a causal solution
>
> 1.2.21)$ ~~~  x(t) = (I - Fz)^{-1}z[Lz(t) + K e(t)]$
>
> where  $(I - Fz)^{-1} = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty F^{j}z^{j}$, provided that the sum in 1.2.21) exists. In this sense, causality is built into the definition of state-space systems.
>
> The transfer functions corresponding to (1.1.22), (1.1.23) are
>
> $k(z) = H(I_{n} - Fz)^{-1}zK + I_{s} = I_{s} + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} HF^{j-1}Kz^{j}$
>
> $l(z) = H(I_{n} - Fz)^{-1} zL = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} HF^{j-1}Lz^{j}$
>
> Starting the system with given initial values $x(0)$, $z(0)$, $\epsilon(0)$ at t = 1, we have
>
> $ x(t) = \sum_{j=1}^{t} F^{j-1}Lz(t-j) + \sum_{j=1}^{t} F^{j-1}K\epsilon(t-1) + F^{t}x(0)$
>
> $y(t) = \sum_{j=1}^{t} HF^{j-1}Lz(t-j) + \sum_{j=1}^{t} HF^{j-1}K\epsilon(t-1) + HF^{t}x(0) + \epsilon_{t}$

The three parts that I don't understand regarding above are

1) the statement about the determinant of $(I-Fz)$ being 1 when $z$ = zero.
I mean I understand why that's true but what does it have to do with the price of tea in china ? or causality ?

2) the derivation of the transfer functions, $k(z)$ and $l(z)$. I do understand 1.2.21) so I imagine that 1.2.21) is used to derive them ????? I also understand the second equalities in $k(z)$ and $l(z)$. But not the first equality signs.

3) the equation for $x(t)$ at the very end. I do see how $y(t)$ is obtained once one has $x(t)$.

I imagine that the material that I'm confused about above ( which is most of it )  is hidden deeply in the 5 pages that I didn't quote but, like I said, I found those pages to be quite "opaque", to say the least.

My guess is that I need is nice reference or lectures notes that explain why, when it comes to the KF,

A) the determinant of $(I-Fz)$  is important and

B) how the associated transfer response functions are obtained  from a state space representation?

C) How the $x(t)$ equation is obtained given the transfer function ?

Note that I'm definitely opened to fighting with this material on my own so even just a good link is fine.

Finally,  if anyone knows of a book that has similar objectives to Hannan
and Deistler but is less concise and shows more steps to things (i.e. doesn't assume as much mathematical maturity ), it's appreciated.

Comment: Your comment about 1) seems spot on: WTF?!?! Hannan and Deistler are more statisticians/ econometricians than EE (having met them both), though Ted was a great statistician and Manfred a great econometrician/EE prof. There are better books out there. My go to book is Anderson and Moore, but many people don't like that. Bounce me a PDF if you can to kootsoop at gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt to answer. It's not complete, and a little fuzzy, but feel free to comment and I can edit / update.

> 1) the statement about the determinant of $(I-Fz)$ being 1 when $z$ = zero.
>   I mean I understand why that's true but what does it have to do with the price of tea in china ? or causality ?

So let's have a look:
$$
x(t+1) = Fx(t) + Lz(t) + K \epsilon(t)\\
zx(t) - Fx(t) = Lz(t) + K \epsilon(t)\\
(I-Fz^{-1})x(t) = z^{-1}[Lz(t) + K \epsilon(t)]\\
x(t) = (I-Fz^{-1})^{-1}z^{-1}[Lz(t) + K \epsilon(t)]\\
$$

One thing to note about this is that $z$ is used twice: once as the lag operator and once as the "reference" signal.  That confused me for a while. Another thing is that they appear to use $z$ as the *lag* operator, whereas $z^{-1}$ is usually used. Above I've assumed the conventional approach to $z$ as the *advance* operator.

My understanding of causality comes from the ROC associated with the $z$ transform.  A $z$-transform is causal if its ROC extends outwards from the outermost pole.  A $z$-transform is BIBO stable if its ROC includes the unit circle.

I believe what they really should have said is:

> Because we assume that $\displaystyle(I - Fz)^{-1} = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty F^{j}z^{j}$, we assume $j\not < 0$ and so assume causality.

which is also sort of implied in their use of state space equations, as they say *In this sense, causality is built into the definition of state-space systems.*

> 2) the derivation of the transfer functions, $k(z)$ and $l(z)$. I do understand 1.2.21) so I imagine that 1.2.21) is used to derive them ????? I also understand the second equalities in $k(z)$ and $l(z)$. But not the first equality signs.

Assuming for now that $L=0$, then the state space form of the $z$ transform of (1.1.22) and (1.1.23) is just:
$$
H(I - z^{-1})K + I
$$
[see these notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap10.pdf), particularly equation (10.20):

[image]

Though they use $A, B, C,$ and $D$ instead of $F, K, H,$ and $I$.

This is just the standard way to represent transfer functions in state space.

> 3) the equation for $x(t)$ at the very end. I do see how $y(t)$ is obtained once one has $x(t)$.

I believe the $x(t)$ equation is just had by the usual solution to a linear, constant coefficient difference equation with non-zero initial conditions (but using their notation). It's not the same notation, [but try this.](https://cnx.org/contents/njHe-mRv@6/Solving-Linear-Constant-Coeffi)

> My guess is that I need is nice reference or lectures notes that explain why, when it comes to the KF,
>
> A) the determinant of $(I-Fz)$  is important and

See answer to 2) above.

> B) how the associated transfer response functions are obtained  from a state space representation?

See references above.

> C) How the $x(t)$ equation is obtained given the transfer function ?

See answer to 3) above.

Comment: Hi Peter : I put a check next to your answer. The first set of notes you point to were so great because they answered questions 2) and 3) perfectly. I still don't understand the causaiity part but I have many books and notes so I'll go through them to see if I can get more clarity on that. Thanks for the link to the notes. They were a true eye opener for me. I didn't even need the second set. All the best and thanks.

Comment: @markleeds : Great! I hope it's some help.